# How to select specific media in build automation with Ant

Tags: install4j

There are two types of media(Windows and Linux) for my C++ based application. so I want to build windows media file on windows machine, Linux media file on Linux machine.

Please let us know the option to pass media-ID to  build automation with Ant

```
<taskdef name="install4j"
               classname="com.install4j.Install4JTask"
               classpath="${env.INSTALL4J_HOME}\bin\ant.jar"/>

    <target name="data-collector-installer">
        <install4j projectfile="${env.SRC_ROOT}\Build\MyApp.install4j"/>
     </target>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute

```
mediatypes="windows"
```

on the `install4j` task to only build media files for windows. To get a list of all media types, execute

```
install4jc --list-media-types
```

on the command line line.

To build a specific media file ID, set the attribute

```
buildids="nnn"
```

on the `install4j` task. You can see the media file IDs in the "Media" section of your project.